# Set function in URB header to URB_FUNCTION_CLASS_INTERFACE

Tags: usb, libusb

I want to know how to set function field in URB header? Is it possible?

I need to send 'Class Interface' request to usb device, but if I send this using control transfer then usb sniffer says its 'control transfer' not 'Class Interface' under its request column.

In URB header in function field I need to set value to URB_FUNCTION_CLASS_INTERFACE. How to do this?